# How to create SQL Tables using Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cli

I just created an Azure SQL Server and Database using Azure CLI [according to these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-create-and-configure-database-cli?toc=%2Fcli%2Fazure%2Ftoc.json). Worked very well.

I'd like to now practice creating TABLES within this database using Azure CLI but there don't appear to be any docs on creating TABLES using this tool.

Can this be accomplished with Azure CLI? If so, please provide some reference materials or guidance.

Thank you

Comment: Check this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-technical-overview#easy-to-use-tools . How to manage and develop in SQL Database using tools.

Comment: If you want to do it from the command line, I guess the SqlServer powershell module is the one you want to use.

Comment: @Llazar, your response doesn't have references for how to use Azure CLI for creating Azure SQL tables within a Database. Its a very general reference.

Comment: @JamesZ, are you saying that it is not possible to create Azure SQL Tables using the Azure CLI tool?

Comment: I'm showing you the Microsoft docs to see what tool you need to manage and develop SqlServer Database. There is no reference how to create tables for databases with CLI.

Comment: "....but there don't appear to be any docs on creating TABLES using this tool." Yep. Hence the OP!

Comment: Why would there be SQL command support in Azure CLI? It's for creating Azure things, not managing SQL Server.

Comment: According to [Azure CLI document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db?view=azure-cli-latest), we could know there is no create table related command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manage the objects and the data using the Azure CLI.  If you want to stay at the command line to do that, take a look at the **sqlcmd** tool.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the engagement. I ended up installing the .mssql extension for VS Code. It is absolutely great.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-mssql.mssql